# DFS over string trie (prefix)

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, prefix-tree

I wrote the following prefix trie:

```
class TrieNode {
    char letter;
    HashMap<Character,TrieNode> children;
    boolean fullWord;

    TrieNode(char letter) {
        this.letter = letter;
        children = new  HashMap<Character, TrieNode>();
        this.fullWord = false;
    }
}

class Tree{
    static TrieNode createTree() {
         return (new TrieNode('\0'));
    }

    static void insertWord(TrieNode root, String word) {
        int l = word.length();
        char[] letters = word.toCharArray();
        TrieNode curNode = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (!curNode.children.containsKey(letters[i]))
                curNode.children.put(letters[i], new TrieNode(letters[i]));
            curNode = curNode.children.get(letters[i]);
        }
        curNode.fullWord = true;
    }
}
```

I would like to add DFS method in order to find the first node that has more than 1 child (so it will show me the longest common prefix).

I wrote this code:

```
static void DFS(TrieNode node) {
    for (TrieNode tn: node.children.values()){
       DFS(tn);
        if (node.children.size()>2)
        System.out.println("found the first vertex");
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 2 edges or children ?

Comment: 2 or more children. This way I will know that until that location it's the longest common prefix

Comment: Please clarify your question, are you looking for the longest common prefix of all the entries that consist of the prefix tree? If that's the case, children.size()>2 is not sufficient. Or are you looking for the longest common prefix of any two strings?

Comment: Yes- of all the entries of the tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first we need to clarify that **longest common prefix** here means the longest common prefix of any two or more strings in the trie tree.

So, your DFS method won't work well because it simply traverse the whole tree and will output "**found the first vertex**" on visiting any node whose children.size() > 2 (*It should be >=2 here*)

What we want here is finding the **longest** common prefix only. So we need some extra information about which is the longest one. It's easy to see that in my example above:

```
          root      --depth: 0
           |
           a        --depth: 1
           |
           b        --depth: 2
          / \
         c   f      --depth: 3
        /|\
       d g k        --depth: 4
            \
             k      --depth: 5
```

The longest common prefix node has children.size()>1 **AND** has max depth. In this case, it's node **c**

So here's one possible correct DFS:

```
static int max=-1;
static TrieNode maxNode=null;

static void dfs(TrieNode node, int depth){
    if(node.children.size()>1 && depth>max){
        max=depth;
        maxNode=node;
    }
    for (TrieNode tn: node.children.values())
        dfs(tn,depth+1);
}

public static void test(){
    TrieNode root = Tree.createTree();
    Tree.insertWord(root, "abcd");
    Tree.insertWord(root, "abcg");
    Tree.insertWord(root, "abckk");
    Tree.insertWord(root, "abf");
    dfs(root,0);
    System.out.println("Max node:"+maxNode.letter);
}
```

After running of dfs, the **maxNode** will hold the node which longest common prefix stops. it's node c in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Your Prefix Tree code seems good. At least it makes sense to me but I haven't checked all corner cases. The problem is you DFS method. Assuming we have the following strings which consist of your prefix tree:

```
- "abcd"
- "abcg"
- "abckk"
- "abf"
```

So the prefix tree should look like this:

```
              root
               |
               a
               |
               b
              / \
             c   f
            /|\
           d g k
                \
                 k
```

I think what you expect is that we can output the "**found the first vertex**" at node **b** (*because obviously "ab" is the longest common prefix of the above four strings*), however, your DFS doesn't work that way. It will go along the way

```
root->a->b->c->d then back to c, finding that c.children.size() >1 , then output.
```

*Note that "**2 or more**" is >=2 or >1 which in your program is >2. I thought that should be a typo.*
To correct your DFS, simply modify it to check a node's children size first will work:

```
static boolean DFS(TrieNode node) {
    if (node.children.size()>1){
        System.out.println("found the first vertex on node:"+node.letter);
        return true;
    }
    for (TrieNode tn: node.children.values()){
        if(DFS(tn))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note to make the program stop on finding our node, I modify the return type of you DFS.
Also, regarding on finding longest common prefix, DFS may not be a best choice here, the following code is better than DFS in terms of runtime complexity:

```
static void lcp(TrieNode node){
    TrieNode first = node;
    while(first.children.size()==1)
        first = first.children.values().iterator().next();
    System.out.println("found the first vertex on node:"+first.letter);
}
```

Comment: Hi, you said  "found the first vertex" at node b (because obviously "ab" is the longest common prefix of the above four strings), but the truth is that in the above case abc is the longest prefix

Comment: @Odelya Do I miss something? The common longest common prefix of the four strings in my example is "ab". Notice the 4th string "abf", it starts only "ab". You said that you're looking for the longest common prefix of all the entries which consist of a prefix tree. Is that right?

Comment: @Odelya  Or you can give me your definition of longest common prefix, give me some examples and I can fix your code.

Comment: The longest common prefix doesn't need to be in ALL the strings - could be also in some of them. This is why abc is longer than ab although it appears only in 3 strings and not in all of them

Comment: @Odelya Well, I have to say this definition is wired. Anyway, you want to find the longest common prefix as long as it appears at least in 2 strings, correct? I will post another answer.